# Save CSV file as a physical file on client machine using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, export-to-csv

I'm currently writing a CSV file in JS and I need to let the user specify the path to which it is saved. Currently it's always saving to the downloads folder. Here's the code I'm using now:

```
let csvData = new Blob([csvString], { type: 'text/csv' });  
let csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvData);

let hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = csvUrl;
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = '/output/output.csv';
hiddenElement.click();
```

And this is the folder I'm trying to save it to fopr testing purposes:

[image: Folder]

Comment: Can't be done. You can set a default file name. You can't override the user's configuration of download folder.